# C circular shift 64 bit not working properly

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, shift

I'm trying to apply a circular bitshift of n bits (varies between 1 and 62) using the << and the >> operators but the result is not coming out as expected...

It works well with circular shifts of 1 but not more (I haven't verified all of them)...

```
uint64_t array[25];
for(i=0;...)
   array[i] = ((s[n] << n) | (s[i] >> (64-n)));
```

Example: 
    ---> Trying to shift this: 00:00:02:26:00:00:00:2D
    ---> I got this:           00:80:80:09:00:00:40:0B

Which doesn't make any sense because I'm not even being able to understand what happened.

Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to do this on a 32 bit machine... maybe it has something to do with that...

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: We don't know the types of all the variables, and I for one don't feel inclined to guess. At the very least you should wrap this in a function and present the entire function. Surely we don't need to see an array of length 25 to work on this. How about an SSCCE?

Comment: Yes, please give us a small function with a single example and what you expect the input and output to be?

Answer (score 2):

use s[i] instead of s[n]:

```
uint64_t array[25];
for(i=0;...)
   array[i] = ((s[i] << n) | (s[i] >> (64-n)));
```

You are mixing together the index variable i and the shift span n which makes little sense in this context. I'm assuming that s is:

```
uint64_t s[25];
```

And no, it's not an architecture issue... uint64_t is an unsigned 64 bit integer both in x86 and ia64 families. In the latter 64bit integers are handled natively by the CPU, in the former you have to use more registers to do the same things...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that type of `*s` is **unsigned** otherwise you will get sign-extended bit shifts.

Also you have `s[n] << n` instead of `s[i] << n`.

Also if you are in x86-64 you may want to consider using the processor instruction:

```
uint64_t temp = s[i];
asm ("rolq %0, %%cl"
     , "+r" (temp)
     : "c" ((uint8_t)n));
array[i] = temp;
```

Comment: you're right but using inline assembly is a little bit overkill here. Compiler will optimize the << | >> stuff for you (actually translating it to a ROL or ROR instruction). Moreover it makes the code unreadable.. much better to stick to a << | >> line and add a little comment to it.

Comment: You don't really need that, GCC recognizes the rotate pattern and emits and actual `rol` (Clang and ICC do as well). I don't know about MSVC, but it wouldn't like the GCC-style inline asm so this doesn't help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should consistently use the index variable to index and the shift count to shift. Then things might work out.